# ¿Es posible fusionar 2 arreglos que vienen de múltiples peticiones Axios?

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, vue.js, mongoose

Tengo estos dos arreglos:

```
0: {_id: '613a09f15dca581998f3e52b', leads_asignados: 1}
1: {_id: '613a0a465dca581998f3e555', leads_asignados: 1}
2: {_id: '613a0a095dca581998f3e537', leads_asignados: 2}
3: {_id: '613a0a3a5dca581998f3e54f', leads_asignados: 1}
4: {_id: '613a09fb5dca581998f3e531', leads_asignados: 1}
6: {_id: '613a0a1f5dca581998f3e543', leads_asignados: 1}
```

```
0: {_id: '613a09f15dca581998f3e52b', leads_atendidos: 1}
1: {_id: '613a0a465dca581998f3e555', leads_atendidos: 1}
2: {_id: '613a0a095dca581998f3e537', leads_atendidos: 1}
3: {_id: '613a0a3a5dca581998f3e54f', leads_atendidos: 1}
4: {_id: '613a09fb5dca581998f3e531', leads_atendidos: 1}
```

Me gustaría fusionarlos en mi frontend de tal forma que los repetidos se agrupen y los que no se repiten quede como cero.
En la imagen inferior he llegado hasta tener todo organizado con vendedores duplicados, me gustaría fusionar los duplicados para tenerlos en una sola fila. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

[image: He llegado hasta aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer lo siguente utilizando un reduce:

1. Combinar ambos arreglos.
2. Para cada elemento del arreglo combinado, vas a verificar si está o no en el acumulador
3. Si no está en el acumulador vas a agregarlo, iniciando en cero la propiedad que no existe.
4. Si está en el acumulador, vas a fusionar el elemento que tienes guardado en el acumulador con el elemento actual.

Te adjunto un fragmento de código funcional. ¡Buena suerte!

```js
const array1 = [
  { _id: '613a09f15dca581998f3e52b', leads_asignados: 1 },
  { _id: '613a0a465dca581998f3e555', leads_asignados: 1 },
  { _id: '613a0a095dca581998f3e537', leads_asignados: 2 },
  { _id: '613a0a3a5dca581998f3e54f', leads_asignados: 1 },
  { _id: '613a09fb5dca581998f3e531', leads_asignados: 1 },
  { _id: '613a0a1f5dca581998f3e543', leads_asignados: 1 }
]

const array2 = [
  { _id: '613a09f15dca581998f3e52b', leads_atendidos: 1 },
  { _id: '613a0a465dca581998f3e555', leads_atendidos: 1 },
  { _id: '613a0a095dca581998f3e537', leads_atendidos: 1 },
  { _id: '613a0a3a5dca581998f3e54f', leads_atendidos: 1 },
  { _id: '613a09fb5dca581998f3e531', leads_atendidos: 1 }
]

const allElements = [...array1, ...array2]

const uniqueElements = allElements.reduce((acc, element) => {
  let i = acc.findIndex(e => element._id === e._id)

  if (i >= 0) {
    Object.assign(acc[i],element)
  } else {
    element.leads_asignados = element.leads_asignados || 0
    element.leads_atendidos = element.leads_atendidos || 0
    acc.push(element)
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(uniqueElements)
```